# How to reassign S2D NVME SSD as cache role

Tags: storage, storage-spaces, windows-server-2019

We are using Hyper-V on a S2D cluster of three nodes. Each node has two NVME SSD's and 8x SAS 1.2TB drives. The NVME SSD's are currently assigned in the performance Tier and the 8 drives are assigned in the capacity tier. On the VM's running in the cluster I am experiencing poor disk performance. I investigated the issue and noticed that the cache has been disabled for S2D.

I enabled the S2D cache with the 'Set-ClusterS2D -CacheState enabled'. The command is returning No disks found to be used for cache. The NVME drives are already part of the storage pool I created earlier. Is there are way to remove the NVME drives(without disruption) from the pool so I can use them as cache device?

Answer (score 2):

You need to devastate your S2D cluster and build new one from the scratch. That’s the only option for now.

Answer (score -1):

i read a article just now regard to replacing S2D hard drives. You can try retire your SSD using Set-PhysicalDisk -Usage Retired command and Repair-VirtualDisk command to free your disk from S2D.